# Android: how to access camera capture when application running at background

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture, image-capture

I have been searching for this to implement to my application.As i understand that i can use broadcast receiver for listen camera capture.But i need more specific information about captured image or video.Also broadcast receiver cod which i found at stackoverflow is only XML.

Imagine that we have a program that working and listening camera.Close our application.Still working at background.Open the android camera(not from our application).Then hit on the capture button.And wait for save picture.Now, there are 2 situations here.

**1st is, if it is possible we should see a window includes "write some tag EditText" or "dont show this again CheckBox".**

**2nd is, we should get path of new captured picture.**

Thus, how can i access between picture save event and capture button with working application at background as service?
If there is only xml way to do this, can you explain how to access picture's path with broadcast receiver?

Thank you in advance.